# What is a good resource for understanding GAE datastore architecture?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Is there a detailed analysis of Google App Engine's datastore architecture somewhere? What I am looking for is a resource that can help me:

1. Understand why a particular restriction exist in datastore (e.g transactions requiring same entity group)
2. Build a deeper understanding of storage mechanics that help me mentally visualize efficiency of a particular data model.

GAE documentation have some good individual articles, but I am looking for more detail treatment, a book perhaps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could start with presentation from Google I/O:

- [App Engine Datastore Under The Covers](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tx5gdoNpcZM)

The [presentation on Appstats](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bvp7CuBWVgA) also gives some insight into how datastore (and RPC calls in general) work, as well as giving some optimization tips.